# contribution page loop with js errors

Tags: civicontribute, javascript

WP 6.03 civi 5.52 payment processor is OmniPay - Eway_RapidShared

Had been working fine - have removed all recent plugins & disabled wordfence, all caches cleared

after clicking contribute the user is returned to the contribute form with values still filled in.
url is civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&_qf_Main_display=true&qfKey=CRMContributeControllerContribution4ue1srzprag4o8gcc8cw4o8kwg80k0skksgwsook4ssg8og4ok_8616
so wordpress page content is no longer displayed at this point

Below are js errors. Civi debug & backtrace enabled but show nothing

[image]

Comment: just realised javascript errors are as soon as wordpress page is loaded - so don't relate to looping phenomena

Comment: Looks like you have some conflicting Javascript.  Maybe look at the network tab and see what non-Civi js is being loaded.